# Try to create a for loop that iteratively adds up the sum of its runs in a total variable

Tags: javascript, scope

I am trying to write a function in Javascript that will return `true` or `false` depending on if the number is an Armstrong number or not.  Armstrong numbers are numbers that take each digit of a number and multiple it by the length of the number, then add them all up to equal the original number.  For example: 153 is an Armstrong number, because: `153 = 1^3 + 5^3 + 3^3 = 1 + 125 + 27 = 153`.

I'm sure my function has other problems and isn't the pretiest but I'm stuck on this.

I've already tried to add `parseInt()` around multiple areas of the function to ensure that I'm only dealing with integers and not strings without any lucky.

```js
const validate = (num) => {
  const numlength = num.toString().length;
  let armstrong;
  let singleDigit;
  for (i = 0; i < numlength; i++) {
    singleDigit = num.toString()[i] ** numlength;
    armstrong += singleDigit;
  }
  if (armstrong == num) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
};

console.log(validate(153))
```

The problem that I'm facing is that the `armstrong` variable is returning `NaN` for some reason.  I'm not quite sure how to iteratively add the `singleDigit` values that are found in the for statement.  When I `console.log(singleDigit)` right after it is figured out in the for statement, the value is correctly.  If I `console.log(armstrong)` right after that, I get `NaN`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set initial value of ***`armstrong = 0`***.

By default it is ***`undefined`*** so when you perform math operation with `undefined` it results in ***`NaN`***

```js
const validate = num => {
  let numString = num.toString()
  const numlength = numString.length;
  let armstrong = 0;
  let singleDigit = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < numlength; i++) {
    singleDigit = numString[i] ** numlength;
    armstrong += singleDigit;
  }
  return armstrong == num
};

console.log(validate(153))
```

---

***On side note:-***

1. You can simply remove the last if else statement, `armstrong == num` is already resulting in `true` or `false`
2. Instead of calling `toString()` on each iteration we can simply store in a variable and use it

---

One more way is to use reduce instead of for loop

```js
const validate = num => {
  let numString = num.toString()
  const numLength = numString.length;
  const armstrong = [...numString].reduce((acc, r) => acc += r ** numLength, 0)
  return armstrong == num
};

console.log(validate(153))
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  Setting my initial value to 0 let the function work like intended.  The other modifications also make complete sense in regards to simplifying finding the length of the number.  Will be looking more into the `.reduce()` method like you also suggested.  Still trying to get better at working with arrays.